# Digitizing control in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am creating a plugin that digitizes a line by "add line feature " in the "Toggle Editing" toolbar, I want the digitized line to be between two points of a point layer which is a layer different than the line layer to avoid adding any random line.

Is controlling the line digitizing possible in PyQGIS?

The digitized data are in PostgreSQL tables

Comment: So, you want to recreate the `snapping` toolbar?

Comment: @Erik No, I am wondering if I can control the digitizing process, for example, if a user wants to digitize a line, it should starts with a point in point layer and end at a point in the same layer, not just click anywhere and create a line

Comment: But ... with snapping, QGIS display a big purple cross on a point layer for example, this is not enough ?